# Honeycomb activity spontaneously restarts itself

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I've got a really odd problem which comes out when testing my app on the Honeycomb emulator. When the "tablet" is rotated to portrait, my main `Activity` seems to just get stuck, and restarts itself over and over again. The stack trace below seems to give no indication of what is going on, and I haven't been able to pinpoint the restart when debugging either. The same thing doesn't occur on a Gingerbread phone, which uses the same portrait layout.

I do not own a Honeycomb device (yet) so I cannot see whether this is a quirk of the emulator or not.

```
08-02 21:28:02.137: INFO/ActivityManager(81): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.espian.formulae.pro/.Host (has extras) } from pid 419
08-02 21:28:02.193: WARN/WindowManager(81): Failure taking screenshot for (354x230) to layer 21010
08-02 21:28:04.136: INFO/ActivityManager(81): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.espian.formulae.pro/.Host (has extras) } from pid 419
08-02 21:28:04.209: WARN/WindowManager(81): Failure taking screenshot for (354x230) to layer 21015
08-02 21:28:04.230: WARN/ActivityManager(81): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-02 21:28:06.127: DEBUG/dalvikvm(419): GC_CONCURRENT freed 105K, 3% free 7353K/7559K, paused 13ms+161ms
08-02 21:28:06.178: WARN/ActivityManager(81): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40841ae0 com.espian.formulae.pro/.Host}
08-02 21:28:06.517: INFO/ActivityManager(81): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.espian.formulae.pro/.Host (has extras) } from pid 419
08-02 21:28:06.567: WARN/WindowManager(81): Failure taking screenshot for (354x230) to layer 21020
08-02 21:28:08.447: INFO/ActivityManager(81): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.espian.formulae.pro/.Host (has extras) } from pid 419
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is that not what I've put above? It just repeats after that

Comment: this is from the Logcat in DDMS

Comment: Sorry, no.  I would suggest seeing if you can run some of the example apps.

Comment: Not to worry, but thank you anyway. Maybe I'll just have to buy myself a Galaxy Tab to test it out... :)

Comment: @Espiandev could you add the `AndroidManifest` and the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem finally! I have a spinner in the ActionBar, and didn't realise the listener was activated when the activity is first created. In landscape this just added another menu to the multiview pane (which I have recently noticed was another bug), but in portrait fires a new activity every time the last one is created.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in manifest under the Actvity tag,  and overriding

```
@Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
```

the above method in the same Activity...

Comment: it still keeps doing it, should I have put anything in this method or just kept it as what you have above?

Comment: just like what i have put. and remember to put in proper Activity. both tag and method..

Comment: have found the error in my code after much hunting (see above), but thank you for your advice anyway